# impresspages 4.0.16. bug in ipAddJs function?

Tags: impresspages

I'd need some help on (IP 4.0.16).
I'm trying to pass parameters to a js file by the function ipAddJs

```
ipAddJs('file.js', array('id' => 123))
```

but in the generated html the result is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/file.js?1" id="123"></script>
```

am i doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: What is unexpected in this? What answer was you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter in `ipAddJs` function is for HTML attributes. Therefore, the result is as expected.

If you want to add variable to a filename, just put it as you want them:

```
ipAddJs('file.js?id=123');
```